# Why is my attempt to use GDB in VS Code to debug C on a Mac failing, and how can I fix it?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, debugging, gdb

I'm using a MacBook with macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and have been trying to get the debugger to work in Visual Studio Code for my C projects.

Initially, I tried using LLDB and managed to get it working a couple of times, but it only opened my system terminal and later stopped working for other codes. So, I moved to GDB, installed it, and created the necessary certificate with Keychain.

I've read that LLDB has limitations that don't allow you to use the internal terminal of Visual Studio Code, which led me to try GDB. I've tweaked the "externalConsole" setting in my launch.json file to both true and false, but nothing seems to make a difference. Ideally I'd like GDB to work rather than LLDB. I've watched almost every tutorial and followed multiple guides, yet I'm still stuck.

I've created the main.out file with manually from the vsc terminal with: `gcc -g main.c -o main.out`

**Here are some additional details:**

**The Code I'm trying to debug: Main.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a,b,c;

    printf("input a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("input another number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    c = a+b;
    printf(" %d + %d = %d\n", a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

**LLDB Version:**
lldb-1200.0.44.2
Apple Swift version 5.3.2 (swiftlang-1200.0.45 clang-1200.0.32.28)
**GDB Version:**
GNU gdb (GDB) 13.2

**launch.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.out",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    }
  ]
}
```

**tasks.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "gcc",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${workspaceFolder}/main.c",
        "-o",
        "${workspaceFolder}/main.out"
      ],
      "group": "build"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you say it's not working. be more descriptive/detailed. what do you actually observe instead of what you expect? Do you get any error dialogs? Any error notifications? Anything in the Problems Panel? Anything in the Output Panel's various channels?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just got tired of it and moved to Xcode. The degugger works perfect by default in it so I'm just using Xcode for the time being.